GTM: best way to manage a script that needs to run on certain routes in Next.js
We're managing a chat plugin using GTM, in our Next.js application.
We want everything to be managed via GTM, no code on the FE.
So GTM takes care of injecting the main script and then GTM takes also care of injecting the init script.
We'd like the chat to be visible only on certain pages, but not others.
Problem. Once loaded, the script is loaded.
Right now it was implemented statically, and that's the reason it doesn't work as expected:
<script>
 window.addEventListener("foo", () => {
    // DO SOMETHING
  });
</script>

So of course once loaded, the callback will fire on every page.
My idea to do this dynamically, would be using dynamic variables, something like this
<script>
     const enableFoo = {{customGTMVariable}};
</script>
<script>
 enableFoo && window.addEventListener("foo", () => {
    // DO SOMETHING
  });
</script>

Can this work or should I go for something using the DataLayer?
I'm not a GTM expert, but our consultants theoretically are.
I want to be prepared when I talk to them in order to address the issue.
Maybe a cookie can be updated at every page change?
The important thing is not touching the FE code. What can be done with GTM can be done.

Either JavaScript variable or DataLayer is quite the same logic. Just need the developer have a flag that which should show and GTM can add trigger rule based on that flag.
In this case I think JavaScript variable will be more suitable.

hey @darrelltw I was reading the question again and maybe it wasn't very clear.
The idea is managing everything via GTM.
I don't want to touch the code. And especially I can't touch the code, cause we froze it for Black Friday period.

oh sorry I didn't know that. But can I confirm that the chat plugin is installed by GTM? Like a custom html tag has the javascript to load the chat plugin.

yes, GTM takes care of loading the main js and also the script that actually loads the chat, that uses the "foo" event to start the chat...

There are many ways. If there is a rule can define which page path or url only needs to show. We can set as trigger so it won't be loaded when the rule not passed.

Thanks man. I'll meet with the GTM expert in the afternoon, I'll update here :)

The solution is

Add an attribute in the dataLayer via GTM
Creating a script that is always loaded and can therefore do 3 things:


Monitor url changes
Clean up the dom
Check the dataLayer to know if the script needs to be run or not

